# JMeter: Passing an string in a request body based on a condition

Tags: jmeter, http-post

I have a request, where I'm sending some values fetched from the response of the previous API calls, as strings within an array.

```
{"content_id":[${identifier_trending_INDIVIDUAL},${identifier_fetch_INDIVIDUAL},${identifier_interestBased_INDIVIDUAL}]}
```

If one of the variables doesn't have any value for e.g.: identifier_fetch_INDIVIDUAL is an empty string, I don't want to pass it. It should be included in the body of the request only when it has a value. Is it possible to achieve this using any preprocessor element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
def payload = [:]

def content = []
content += vars.get('identifier_trending_INDIVIDUAL') ?: []
content += vars.get('identifier_fetch_INDIVIDUAL') ?: []
content += vars.get('identifier_interestBased_INDIVIDUAL') ?: []

payload.put('content_id', content)

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

You can reference generated value in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler's body as `${payload}`

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Elvis Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_elvis_operator)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I used the same code, but backward slashes are attached at the beginning and end of each string. It is looking like this: "content_id": [
        "\"123\",\"456\",\"789\",\"12345\""]
Any idea why the strings are modified like this?

Comment: Maybe because you variables contain quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, it contains quotations, as it is a string and needs to be passed in the same format.

Comment: You have 2 choices: either amend your variables extraction logic to not to include quotation marks or to amend the above Groovy code to remove these quotation marks.

Comment: Yeah, I tried a lot of ways, but I'm unable to remove the quotation marks.